# Crawling - specific word

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am crawling a website where I need to grab sentence starting with "Confirmed ..."

The html for corresponding sentence looks like this

```
<span class='text-secondary ml-2 d-none d-sm-inline-block'
    title='Estimated duration between time First Seen and included in block'> | <i class='fal fa-stopwatch ml-1'></i>
    Confirmed within 25 secs</span>
```

Using [requests_html](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) from Python I can retrieve:

```
r.html.find("span", containing="Confirmed "
```

[<Element 'span' class=('text-secondary', 'ml-2', 'd-none', 'd-sm-inline-block') title='Estimated duration between time First Seen and included in block'>]`

But for some reason, it doesn't return the rest. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to find `span` element using parameter string "Confirmed "?

Like this:

```
r.html.find("span", containing="Confirmed ")
```

I do some testing in localhost using your html and it does return the element : [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRjEq.png)

Comment: yes i tried that already.